# My OpenDMARC is rejecting emails from firefox.com . Is their SPF record correct? Or am I wrong?

Tags: postfix, spf, dmarc, opendkim, opendmarc

Why is opendmarc rejecting mail from firefox.com?  It looks like their SPF record matches their sending address and does pass:

```
v=spf1 mx a include:amazonses.com include:mail.zendesk.com -all
```

/var/log/maillog:

```
postfix/smtpd[19221]: connect from a59-48.smtp-out.us-west-2.amazonses.com[54.240.59.48]
postfix/smtpd[19221]: Anonymous TLS connection established from a59-48.smtp-out.us-west-2.amazonses.com[54.240.59.48]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
postfix/smtpd[19221]: 559B1453AE7: client=a59-48.smtp-out.us-west-2.amazonses.com[54.240.59.48]
postfix/cleanup[19242]: 559B1453AE7: message-id=<01010174e1286c9e-b6d5f59b-d47f-4978-8979-ddc31c5b6170-000000@us-west-2.amazonses.com>
opendkim[25641]: 559B1453AE7: a59-48.smtp-out.us-west-2.amazonses.com [54.240.59.48] not internal
opendkim[25641]: 559B1453AE7: not authenticated
opendkim[25641]: 559B1453AE7: message has signatures from firefox.com, amazonses.com
opendkim[25641]: 559B1453AE7: DKIM verification successful
opendmarc[25631]: 559B1453AE7 ignoring Authentication-Results at 1 from ip-172-31-2-211.ec2.internal
opendmarc[25631]: 559B1453AE7: SPF(mailfrom): 01010174e1286c9e-b6d5f59b-d47f-4978-8979-ddc31c5b6170-000000@us-west-2.amazonses.com pass
opendmarc[25631]: 559B1453AE7: **firefox.com fail**
postfix/cleanup[19242]: 559B1453AE7: milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from a59-48.smtp-out.us-west-2.amazonses.com[54.240.59.48]: 5.7.1 rejected by DMARC policy for firefox.com; from=<01010174e1286c9e-b6d5f59b-d47f-4978-8979-ddc31c5b6170-000000@us-west-2.amazonses.com> to=<redacted@redacted.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<a59-48.smtp-out.us-west-2.amazonses.com>
```

Comment: If you add your configuration, the mistake would probably be more obvious. Specifically, look for `AuthservID` in your `opendkim.conf` and `opendmarc.conf`!

Answer (score 0):

In *DMARC* the rules about which address matters are described as *identifier alignment*, and describe the manner in which the *SPF*-authenticated domain must match the domain the *From*-Header.

You are looking at logs for a mail that is not *aligned* in that sense: I can tell from your *opendmarc* logs that you were receiving a mail that was checked for alignment with `firefox.com` - but the SPF authorization above refers to `.amazonses.com`.

I cannot tell with certainty from your logs what excactly happened to the other method, *DKIM*.  You can best figure out that part by receiving mail from a known-good sender and looking at  the `Authentication-Results:` headers. I suspect the *ignored* header from `ip-172-31-2-211.ec2.internal` is yours, in that place opendkim & opendmarc should probably be configured to use something globally unique (`172.16.0.0/12` is NOT), such as your MX FQDN instead.

Comment: Are you saying their  SPF record is wrong?  Did they incorrectly omit their sending domain (firefox.com) even though all mail comes from a amazonses IP?  And yes, ip-172-31-2-211.ec2.internal is me.

Comment: @Andrew If that header is yours, why are you `ignoring` it? You should fix your *opendkim* and *opendmarc* configuration.